# Maven Dependency Error for bot-connector and bot-schema version 4.0.0-SNAPSHOT?

Tags: maven, botframework

I'm in the process of updating a bot that was already created, however I am receiving the following maven errors when attempting to compile the bot before making any changes:

```
Failure to find com.microsoft.bot.connector:bot-connector:pom:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT in https://botbuilder.myget.org/F/botbuilder-v4-java-daily/maven/ was cached in the local repository

Failure to find com.microsoft.bot.schema:botbuilder-schema:pom:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT in https://botbuilder.myget.org/F/botbuilder-v4-java-daily/maven/ was cached in the local repository
```

I tried going through the version history of the two dependencies but I could not find the specified version (4.0.0-SNAPSHOT) there either. The bot library works by itself as a jar however so it seems that the dependency versions did exist at a certain point. It appears as though the previous dependency versions no longer exist currently? I'm not sure if I should just try to find a working stable version of the dependencies and use that instead or maybe the existing dependency version can still be found somewhere?

Comment: Because the java sdk of the bot framework is still in preview, I recommend you raise this on [Botbuilder-java](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java/issues)